# how can I find alternative package?

Tags: r

i was wondering if you could guide me which package can I use instead of Biostrings. because when I installed

```r
install.packages("Biostrings")
```

I get this error:

> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere.

Comment: It is a Bioconductor package.  You need `BiocManager::install("Biostrings")`.  Check [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html)

Comment: `if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Biostrings")`

Comment: The rest of the error message is "see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages". Did you look at that?